# Should questions with no clear motivation be downvoted?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

Should questions with no clear motivation be downvoted?

By "motivation" I mean what led me to ask the question and what sort of answers would be helpful.

I asked a similar question on [philosophy stackexchange](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/do-we-need-to-explain-why-we-are-asking-a-question-on-philosophy-stackexcange/3317#3317).

Comment: Downvoting this question because I do not see any clear motivation.

Comment: Just kidding. Nonetheless, please [edit] your question to clarify what exactly you mean by clear motivation and why you are asking. This way we can better answer it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft i think adding the example that generated the question would just confuse the issue in this instance. any better as it is now?

Comment: I'm not sure if by motivation he meant reason but I would have had a similar question.  I've found myself reading some (many) questions and asking myself 'what the heck is this guy thinking'.  Perhaps if they wrote why, the reason, they ask the question the relevance of the question would be clear and hence prevent people from downvoting (if that's the goal).

Comment: Not wishing to nitpick but I am a bit confused - you say that you _asked_ the same question on Philosophy.Meta, yet, your link points to an _answer_ to the same question... unless you have two accounts and you are also [MATHEMETICIAN](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/6917/mathemetician) who _asked_ the question on Philosophy.Meta. Actually, that could be three accounts, as the link you point to was an answer by [Dan Bron](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/6692/dan-bron). So,  in addition to being user329056, are you also _Dan Bron_, or _MATHEMATICIAN_, or both? :-)

Comment: @Greenonline  He is not Dan Bron. Though he'd say that if he were, wouldn't he? (Though, no, seriously, he is not.)

Comment: @DanBron - Thanks for clearing that up. One down, one to go (i.e. MATHEMATICIAN)... :-)

Comment: @user3293056 why do you think they should or shouldn't be?

Comment: @MonicaCellio i don't think they should be but my questions are often downvoted or closed because no-one knows why i asked them, rather than being off topic or an unclear *question*, etc.

Comment: @user3293056 you should [edit] further info into your questions rather than just answering in comments.  I don't know about your questions in particular, but on one of my sites we sometimes get random-seeming one-liner questions -- no motivation, no reason to suspect there *is* an answer within our context, no clear connection to anything else on our site or in our domain, nothing like that.  Those tend to get downvoted.

Comment: @MonicaCellio hmm *answers within the context* is likely the issue. i tend to use stackexchange to ask questions that have no clear answer on the internet. it may be annoying everyone, but i think that's one of the joys of the subject, **difficult** questions

Comment: @user3293056 a difficult question needs to be *interesting* enough for people to bother to invest effort in answering it.  One-liner "I wonder if" questions that might not even matter to the asker aren't going to do that.  Explain why it matters.  (I guess I'll putt this in an answer now.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about your questions in particular, but on one of my sites we sometimes get random-seeming one-liner questions -- no motivation, no reason to suspect there *is* an answer within our context, no clear connection to anything else on our site or in our domain, nothing like that. Those tend to get downvoted.

You said in a comment:

> i tend to use stackexchange to ask questions that have no clear answer on the internet. it may be annoying everyone, but i think that's one of the joys of the subject, difficult questions

You might think you're asking difficult questions, but if you aren't putting any effort into context, they probably aren't coming across that way.  They're more likely to be coming across as random thoughts.  Random thoughts are easy; the Internet is full of them.  You have to give the community some reason to care about your question; if you don't, it's just noise getting in the way of the content those people came for.

"Difficult" isn't the problem.  Lots of people like a good, meaty question, the sort of question that prompts one to say "huh, I never thought about it that way before and I don't know either; let's see what we can find out".  **But** just because it's interesting to *you* (maybe because of that context you didn't share) doesn't mean it is to anybody else.  A difficult question needs to be interesting enough for people to bother to invest effort in answering it.

One-liner "I wonder if" questions that might not even matter to the *asker* aren't going to do that.  Explain why it matters.  And if you're asking because it's hard, tell us what you've already tried -- nobody likes doing work only to get a comment saying "yeah, I already tried that".  Great, the person trying to help you says, you've wasted my time.

Answer (score 12):

The tooltip on the downvote arrow states

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not
>   useful

Supplying a motivation for asking may make it more evident why some theoretical question is useful in the real world, or act to clarify what you are asking, but it is by no means a pre-requisite for all questions on all sites.

Often the motivation is obvious. e.g. someone asking on the cooking site [Why did my omelette turn gray?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17974/why-did-my-omelette-turn-gray) doesn't need to explain that their motivation for asking is that they don't like gray omelettes.

Comment: think the issue in the question that generated the discussion was "may make it more evident why some theoretical question is useful" it's unclear, in extreme examples, that some questions are helpful until they have good answers.

Comment: @user3293056 - So in cases where the question may come across as completely useless and a waste of time for everyone involved you might consider including a motivation to persuade people that it is not "not useful" but that doesn't mean every question requires this.

Answer (score 5):

Of course not. There is zero reason for askers to waste time justifying their rationale for asking the question unless it's directly relevant to the question. Otherwise, it's just noise. If clarification is needed it can be asked for in the comments. A good question does not necessarily become a bad question just because you don't know why it is being asked.

Downvote a question if it is not clear. Whether or not a lack of explanation of the motivation for asking is what makes it unclear is not important, only that it is unclear. So if it is clear, without explanation, it is fine.

On a more fundamental level this sometimes boils down to having respect for the asker as an intelligent human being who has thought about their question before asking it, even if you don't personally understand why. Granted this is not always the case on some sites, but if you always start off with this level of respect, it shows in your interactions (whether you realize it or not) and generally everybody becomes happier at the end of the day.

Comment: In fact, there are even times when an asker may have omitted irrelevant motivations specifically out of consideration for readers. If leaving out explanation makes the question even *clearer*, then that's a *good* thing, and in those cases you should actually give a nod to the asker for sparing you the gory details.